# Does the Netgear WPN511 PCMCIA card work with 64bit natty?

Tags: networking, 64-bit

Hello fellow Ubuntu users!

I am looking to purchase the Netgear WPN511 PCMCIA card to use with Ubuntu Natty 64-bit. Does this card work with 64-bit Ubuntu? If it does not, can someone recommend a PCMCIA wireless card that will work on 64-bit Natty?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reported to work with Lubuntu 11.04 out of the box, see the link below.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsNetgear#PCMCIA

PS: WPN511 is the last entry in the PCMCIA table.

Comment: I saw that it works with Lubuntu, but I assumed that it was describing 32bit *ubuntu and not 64bit *ubuntu. I am looking into getting this just so I can use a fully functioning 64bit Ubuntu system.

Comment: Yea, it's most definitely a 32bit Lubuntu on P3. I'd say it should most probably work, as there are really no compatibility issues these days with 32/64bit open source drivers.

Comment: So does this mean that even the 32bit drivers will work correctly with 64bit Linux if no native 64bit drivers are available?

Comment: No, I don't think 32bit drivers will work on a 64bit OS, but since the card is reported to work out of the box, the driver must be in the kernel, which usually entails 64bit support.